# is this related to mirror function? are there any solutions for this problem?

Tags: mirror

I would like to know if someone had the same error before, i think its related to mirroring, any ideas?

[image: mirror function]

Comment: did you check "merge" and increase the value a bit?

Comment: Also make sure "Clipping" is enabled

Comment: Also move the mirror modifier before the subdivision surface modifier.

Comment: Also check if you don't have inner faces